# VPN - force a selective range of ip to run on VPN (linux)

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, networkmanager

**Preface:**
I know there are similar question here and there however I'm a kind of newbie on Net stuff so I need an answer on this specific scenario, hoping that can help others too as it is a common problem

Let say **I cannot do anything on the local switch** to change the local ip range, I don't want to use any complicate trick as use VMachine to hide the local ip range but I want to use net tools to solve the issue.

**Scenario**

my **local net** assign me an **IP** of this class 192.168.1.xxx (ex. 192.168.1.116) 
and **my VPN** (**VPNC**) assign me **IP** of same class 192.168.1.xxx (ex. 192.168.1.247)

Obviously I need VPN to access local address (ex. **192.168.1.100**) but when I open any address of the class 192.168.1.xx the route point to my local net and not to the VPN ones.

I'm on linux and i'd like gui solution (network manager) in case it is not possible let play with `route` command.

here what network manager offer me:
[image]

Here my actual route once connected to the VPN:

Here some route information (`route -n`)

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlan0
xxx.YY.ZZ.106   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
xxx.YY.ZZ.106   192.168.1.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     9      0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.246   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
```

Here my `ifconfig` :

```
ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:192.168.1.247  P-t-P:192.168.1.246  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
      RX packets:3415 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:2525 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:3682328 (3.6 MB)  TX bytes:402315 (402.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 4c:eb:42:06:a3:a6  
      inet addr:192.168.1.116  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::4eeb:42ff:fe06:a3a6/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:72598 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:42300 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0                                                  
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000                                                                              
      RX bytes:76000532 (76.0 MB)  TX bytes:13919400 (13.9 MB)
```

**The Question**
So basically I would like to add a rule to force this particular address (**192.168.1.100**) on the VPN and not on my local net

**Solution** - Thanks to Paul

This command will route the 192.168.1.100 host out of the VPN:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.100 dev ppp0
```

This is for the command line, but you can add it above in the dialog box of the first image.

```
Address: 192.168.1.100
Netmask: 255.255.255.255
Gateway: 192.168.1.246
```

Se below answer for detail

Comment: I know my english is far to be perfect :) and my networking terminology could not be accurate so if you find that the question is not clear or contains semantic error please fell free to enhance it

Comment: Hello - can you [edit] your scenario.  You refer to .116 and .247 and explain what they are, but then you bring in .100 without explaining it.  Is this local or over the VPN?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand.  I get that you can't change the local IP address range, but if the VPN is yours, can you change the IP addresses it gives out?

Comment: I cannot change VPN ip address too, you know server admin ... they complain they have to change a too many static ip on office side

Comment: I have added some more info to undestand the scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have a problem in any case.  This command will route the 192.168.1.100 host out of the VPN:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.100 dev ppp0
```

This is for the command line, but you can add it above in the dialog box of the first image.

```
Address: 192.168.1.100
Netmask: 255.255.255.255
Gateway: 192.168.1.246  (the ubuntu vpnc client does not let you specify a device)
```

Your problem is that 192.168.1.100 will need to route back to you.  So it will see packets coming from 192.168.1.247 and think that this address is on its local network.  So it will then broadcast on the local network asking who has the IP address, and it will go unanswered.

So you need the same route back.  But this doesn't help you, because you are over a VPN and your IP address is changing.  This route added to 192.168.1.100 would tell it that .247 is behind the VPN gateway:

```
ip route add 192.168.1.247 via xxx.YY.ZZ.106 [ip address of vpn server]
```

This will only last as long as you remain on .247  As soon as you disconnect and reconnect, you'll have another IP address, and need to change the route.

The golden rule here is that you should avoid using the same address range for both ends of the VPN.

Comment: The second route must be added to 192.168.1.100 - the box you are trying to get to.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: adding this `ip route add 192.168.1.100 dev ppp0` was enough to solve the issue thanks very much

Comment: @Francesco If you get the same IP each time, this should be ok.